# How much external data is too much? (XML or JSON)

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I have written pure JavaScript front ends before and started noticing performance decrease when working with large stores of data. I have tried using xml and json, but in both cases, it was a lot for the browser to handle.

That poses my question, which is how much is too much?

Comment: Isn't this dependant on the browser you are using and the OS?

Answer (score 3):

You can't know, not exactly and not always.  You can make a good guess.

It depends on the browser, OS, RAM, CPU, what else is running at that moment, how fast their connection is, what else they're transferring, etc.

Figure out several situations you expect for your average user, and test those.  Add for various best, worst, and interesting (e.g. mobile, tablet) cases.

You can, of course, apply experience and extrapolate from your specific cases, and the answer will change for the future.

---

But don't fall into the trap of "it works for me!"

I commonly see this with screen resolutions: as those have increased, it's much more popular to have multiple windows visible at the same time.  In 1995 it was rare for me to *not* have something maximized; now fifteen years later, it's exactly the opposite.

Yet sometimes people will design some software or a website, use lower contrast<sup>[1]</sup>, maximize it, and connect to a server on localhost—and that's the only evaluation they do.

<sup>[1] Because they know what the text says and don't need to read it themselves, so lower contrast looks aesthetically better.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, if you need to stop and think about this issue, then the data is too much. In general you should design your applications so that users with a low-end netbooks and/or slow internet connections are still able to run them. Also keep in my mind that more often than not your application isn't the only page your users are visiting at the same time.

My recommendation is to use Firefox with Firebug to do some measurements. See how long a request takes to complete in a modest configuration. If it takes noticeable time for the browser to render data, then you'd better off doing a redesign.

Comment: Yes, good point about the netbooks. Also, has anybody else noticed how hard it is nowadays to find a notebook with more than 768 vertical pixels?  We're actually losing real estate ...

Answer (score 2):

A good guiding principle should be that instead of worrying about whether the *browser* can handle the volume of data you're sending it, worry about whether your *user* can handle it. It all depends on the presentation of course (i.e., a lot of data bound for a visualization tool that'll render a complex graph in a canvas is different than a lot of raw numbers bound for a gigantic table), but in my experience a user's brain reaches data overload before the browser/network/client computer.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the form that your external data is going to take in your Javascript. If you want to load all your data at once and keep it in memory as a large object with lots of properties (associative array), then you will find that most current desktops can only handle about 100k entries (with small key-value pairs) before performance really degrades.

If it is possible, you should see if there are ways to only load the data that is needed by the user for a given request / interaction. You can use AJAX to request needed data and prefetch data that you think the user may need.